# JSF: how to hide outputText when validateLongRange fails

Tags: validation, jsf

I have the following code:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="inputField" value="#{bean.myProperty}">
        <f:validateLongRange
            minimum="#{bean.minimum}"
            maximum="#{bean.maximum}"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" >
        <f:ajax execute="inputField" render="outputField errors" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:outputText id="outputField" value="#{bean.myPropertyFormatted}"/>
    <h:message id="errors" for="inputField"/>
</h:form>
```

When validation fails on the inputText, I would like to remove/hide the outputText from the user. What is the most elegant and future-refactoring-proof way to do this?

I tried setting the attribute `rendered="#{!facesContext.validationFailed}"` on the outputText element, but that only determines whether or not the outputText element is RE-rendered, as opposed to leaving the old text unchanged. However, when the validateLongRange validation fails, I want to completely remove/hide the outputText from the user, since the user will be seing the validation error message and is not interested in seing an old output message based on a previous, valid input which is still the value stored in the bean.

Comment: I don't understand why `rendered` doesn't do the job. If EL inside it returns false `outputText` element will not be rendered, which means you will not have HTML of that element in browser at all. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: @partlov: Yes, that's what I would need, but that's not the behavior I'm seeing. Instead, when I have a validation error, the `outputText` just stays the same, unchanged. I want it to disappear instead. If I invert the EL output (without the "!"), it's easier to see what's going on. With `rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}"` I don't get any update on the `outputText` for valid values, but I get an update as soon as I give an invalid value which results in a validation error. i.e. upon validation error I see the last valid value I entered before entering an invalid value.

Comment: @partlov: could the reason my code is not behaving as you would have expected be tied to the use of the f:ajax element? See also the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you set `rendered` attribute to an object and its value is `false`, the component won't be in the component tree because is not rendered and you can't re-render (or update) it. The solution is to set the component inside an `UIContainer` and render the container:

```
<h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" >
    <f:ajax execute="inputField" render="pnlResult" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:panelGrid id="pnlResult">
    <h:outputText id="outputField" value="#{bean.myPropertyFormatted}"
        rendered="#{not facesContext.validationFailed}" />
    <h:message id="errors" for="inputField"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 5):

As a rule of thumb in JSF, if you want to conditionally render **anything**, you should wrap it in a container component (`<foo:panel/>`) and make the container component the target of the ajax update.

```
<h:form>
   <h:inputText id="inputField" value="#{bean.myProperty}">
      <f:validateLongRange
        minimum="#{bean.minimum}"
        maximum="#{bean.maximum}"/>
   </h:inputText>
   <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" >
      <f:ajax execute="inputField" render="thePanel errors" />
   </h:commandButton>
   <h:panelGrid id="thePanel">
   <h:outputText rendered="#{!facesContext.validationFailed}" id="outputField" value="#{bean.myPropertyFormatted}"/>
   </h:panelGrid>
   <h:message id="errors" for="inputField"/>
</h:form>
```

For a component to be ajax-updated, it must already be in the DOM in the browser, this is the way ajax works. So when your view is initially rendered, `outputField` doesn't exist due to the `rendered` condition evaluating to false. So any subsequent request to ajax update it will fail, because of the reason aforementioned. The container component strategy is to ensure that there's a blanket update of a region of markup, regardless of whatever was there prior

Comment: You posted your answer while I was finishing mine. By the way, you forgot to wrap the `<h:outputText>` and `<h:message>` inside the `UIContainer`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, i was editing when yours showed up! It's a sharkpool out here XD. You've earned my vote

Comment: You're welcome :). Complete your answer so I can upvote you (note that you're not re-rendering `thePanel`).

Comment: @kolossus: Thanks for your answer. I had a hard time deciding which of the two simultaneous answers to checkmark! I hope you forgive me for accepting the other. Both seem equally valid. One thing may still be missing in your answer. You don't have the "not" before `facesContext.validationFailed`. Can you comment on that?

Comment: @Student, it's all good, the better answer got the vote ^_^, the missing `!` was just a typo on my part

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following, based on the excellent answers of kolossus and Luiggi Mendoza:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="inputField" value="#{bean.myProperty}">
        <f:validateLongRange
            minimum="#{bean.minimum}"
            maximum="#{bean.maximum}"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" >
        <f:ajax execute="inputField" render="outputField errors" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="outputGroup">
        <h:outputText id="outputField" value="#{bean.myPropertyFormatted}" rendered="#{not facesContext.validationFailed}"/>
        <h:message id="errors" for="inputField"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

I opted for `h:panelGroup` instead of `h:panelGrid` because my web developer background makes me shudder at the idea of table-based layout. It seems together with `layout="block"`, `h:panelGroup` is rendered as `<div/>`, whereas `h:panelGrid` is rendered as a `<table/>`.